# Query to get the Shipping Method and Payment Terms of Sales Order

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher, oracle-ebs

I'm creating a report that contains details of sales order per order number in BI Publisher using Oracle Fusion Cloud r13. Now, my problem is, I can't find the table that contains the `shipping method` and `payment terms`. I tried to search it to Google but I can't find anything that can help me. Can someone here knows what the query for it is? Or the table only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These should help you. You'll have to do some more digging to know what exactly these do and how to link to them.

Don't forget about `select * from all_tab_cols` you can query against that to find any table that has a column your looking for.

Also, while in Oracle EBS, there's always the help, diagnostics, examine which should get you the field. And record history will give you the table/view name

**Ship Method**

```
oe_order_headers_all.shipping_method_code
wsh_trips.ship_method_code
wsh_new_deliveries.ship_method_code
wsh_delivery_details.ship_method_code
wsh_carrier_ship_methods
wsh_carrier_services
```

**Payment terms**

```
oe_order_headers_all.payment_term_id
ra_terms_tl.payment_term_id
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this but when I tried to use the ```oe_order_headers_all``` I got an error message ```Table or view does not exist```. The data source I used in data model is ```ApplicationDB_FSCM```

Comment: That's what it is in Oracle EBS r12. I see you tagged with oracle-ebs. ApplicationDB_FSCM looks to be fusion entity. Do you have the correct access as a DB user?

Comment: Oh sorry my fault for tagging the Oracle EBS. Yes, my access in the oracle fusion is admin. When I search in google, ```Distributed Order Orchestration``` is the table used for Sales Order. But I check all the table inside the Distributed Order Orchestration and I found only the ```term_id```, ```CARRIER_ID```, ```SHIP_MODE_OF_TRANSPORT```, ```SHIP_CLASS_OF_SERVICE``` which I don't know where to link to. Can you help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have no exposure to Fusion.

Comment: It's okay. But Thanks for the effort!